# How to change date format in Email Template of Dynamics365?

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I want to get the date in this format -
MM-dd-yy.
For example: 10-12-23

I'm writing this code but don't getting the desired solution -

```
<a href="{!<entity_name>;}">{<entity_name>:<attribute>/@date;} Check-In Link</a>
```

What should I write in the `date` part?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the only way to make it work is to set the user's locale to a locale that uses MM-dd-yy format.
Alternatively, it's possible to create a custom string field, populate that field with a properly formatted date and use the value of it in your template.